# react-native-video only play first few seconds of video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Anyone knows how to only play the first few seconds, and repeat it in a react-native video?

I have a profile page which displays all the videos of the user. Currently its playing the whole video but i only want the first few seconds (something like Tiktok).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no sense in doing it that way. Probably TikTok takes the "five seconds" and transforms it into GIF using something like a GIFIFY (https://github.com/jclem/gifify). If someone asked me to do this, I would certainly do so.

EDIT:
I think that you can create a code/component that displays only the X seconds, I think its possible

Comment: thanks. i think i'd do that. since i am already doing ffmpeg on my node server to compress the video, i could also ffmpeg to create the first 5 secs and save it down

Comment: Perfect @DanielShen! When you're done, let me know if you've solved your case.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution without having to create a GIF? I'd love to do this but having to use FFMPEG is not ideal

Comment: You can cut five seconds and host the video on MUX (mux.com), for example. So, you will have two videos, the full video and the small video. The small video you can display in timeline app, when user tap/click on it, you open the full video. What you think?

Comment: Of course it can make sense to do that. For instnace with streaming urls you might want to be able to just loop a certain part.  Or you might want to create an application where users can create their own loops

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just loop the first seconds, just add an onProgress and send back to starting second when it passes a certain second:

```
class Video extends Component {
  render() {

      const {source, YOUR_VARIABLE_FOR_SECONDS} = this.props;
     
      return <VideoPlayer
        source={source}
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.player = ref
        }}
        onProgress={({currentTime}) => {
          if (currentTime > YOUR_VARIABLE_FOR_SECONDS) {
            this.player.seek(0)
          }
        }}
      />
    }
}
```